# AppendChield не работает

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Имею проблему: не могу создать элемент в javascript. Невозможно даже пустой div в документ засунуть.

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Мне выдает ошибка в консоли: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at lesson4.js:421

a div не создается.
Как правильно создать html файл в js, что я делаю не так? Помогите, пожалуйста)

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rNWjeqQ работает же

Answer (score 2):

У меня есть предположение, что вы подключаете .js файл в head, попробуйте подключить перед закрывающим тегом `body`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...

    <script src="lesson4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) Подключил в head, а не в body. Только недавно начал учить js)

Comment: Нажмите на стрелочку вверх, если ответ был полезен и на галочку, если ответ решает вашу проблему. Удачи в изучении)